# Spring Data CRUD findByOrderBy number sorting is incorrect. Sorting 10 as 1

Tags: html, spring-data-jpa, crud

When I am using the CRUD Repository and using the findTop10ByOrderBy method, it will not sort the integers correctly.

Thank you

Result

```
Top Ten Songs
9  - 9  - 9
8  - 8  - 8
7  - 7  - 7
6  - 6  - 6
5  - 5  - 5
4  - 4  - 4
3  - 3  - 3
2  - 2  - 2
10 - 10 - 10
1  - 1  - 1
```

Repository

```java
public interface LookRepository extends CrudRepository<Look, Long>{
   List<Look> findAll();
   List<Look> findByArtistContaining(String artist);
   List<Look> findTop10ByOrderByRatingDesc();
}
```

Service

```java
public List<Look> searchTopTen() {
  return lookRepository.findTop10ByOrderByRatingDesc();
}
```

Controller

```java
@RequestMapping("/TopTen")
public String TopTen(Model model) {
  List<Look> looks = lookService.searchTopTen();
  model.addAttribute("looks", looks);
  return "topten.jsp";
}
```

Comment: Please share the implementation of the function `findTop10ByOrderByRatingDesc()`

Comment: @Satpal What would be my implementation? Using the CRUD repo to implement this function. Would it be my view? Thank for the answer!